# Jupyter notebook failing to connect to kernel in Python 3.4 virtual environment on Mac

Tags: python, python-3.x, virtualenv, jupyter

I am using a Mac running MacOS 10.11.6 (El Capitan). I have Python versions 2.7 and 3.4 installed as Frameworks downloaded from python.org.
Relatively recently, I also installed Python 3.6 using Anaconda because I needed some libraries that I was unable to install by any other way.

Over the years, I have created numerous virtual environments with Python 3.4 using:

```
$ virtualenv -p /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin/python3 env34
```

And activate the environment using:

```
$ source env34/bin/activate
```

I've installed numerous packages including numpy, pandas and jupyter using:

```
(env34) $ pip install package_name
```

This has always worked well.

Recently, however, (after a break from Python coding of 4 months or so) I've tried to do the same but pip did not working and I had to install the latest version using get-pip.py as follows:

```
(env34) $ python get-pip.py
```

That has allowed me to install all the packages I need into the virtual environment. All the installations seemed to progress with no problem.

However, when I now run:

```
(env34) $ jupyter notebook
```

...the jupyter homepage opens as expected but no .ipynb files (either newly created or previously saved files) work. There is a long list of issues generated in the Terminal window, the last few lines of which are:

```
AttributeError: '_UnixSelectorEventLoop' object has no attribute 'is_closed'
[W 21:52:53.476 NotebookApp] Timeout waiting for kernel_info reply from 370a344d-73f3-4d47-899e-0a9250230881
[E 21:52:53.479 NotebookApp] Error opening stream: HTTP 404: Not Found (Kernel does not exist: 370a344d-73f3-4d47-899e-0a9250230881)
[W 21:52:53.986 NotebookApp] KernelRestarter: restart failed
[W 21:52:53.987 NotebookApp] Kernel fa941bc9-f848-4339-bbb3-6dd120a9590e died, removing from map.
[W 21:53:39.000 NotebookApp] Timeout waiting for kernel_info reply from fa941bc9-f848-4339-bbb3-6dd120a9590e
[E 21:53:39.001 NotebookApp] Error opening stream: HTTP 404: Not Found (Kernel does not exist: fa941bc9-f848-4339-bbb3-6dd120a9590e)
```

Is this something I am doing wrong, is Anaconda interfering or has a recent update of the jupyter package introduced a bug?

EDIT

As requested, when I first launched jupyter notebook, the following nbserver file was created in ~/Library/Jupyter/runtime:

```
{
  "base_url": "/",
  "hostname": "localhost",
  "notebook_dir": "/Users/path_to_virtual_environment",
  "password": false,
  "pid": 5022,
  "port": 8888,
  "secure": false,
  "token": "4cd65924e50aa87bba1d18ce1fa50b1ce50f9faacf0cce95",
  "url": "http://localhost:8888/"
}
```

And when I attempted to open an ipynb file, the following kernel file was created:

```
{
  "key": "7c487ae2-3fbe631137bfbf14d419bb53",
  "stdin_port": 60735,
  "control_port": 60736,
  "shell_port": 60733,
  "transport": "tcp",
  "signature_scheme": "hmac-sha256",
  "ip": "127.0.0.1",
  "hb_port": 60737,
  "iopub_port": 60734,
  "kernel_name": ""
}
```

Comment: Can you find and show your Jupyter kernel file?

Comment: @cricket_007 Thanks for the response. I've pasted the contents of the nbserver file and the kernel file that were created when jupyter notebook was launched and when the ipynb file is opened.

Comment: Try `cd ~/Library/Jupyter/kernels/` then look for some folders and `kernel.json` in there

Comment: Also, Anaconda should have installed its own environment along with jupyter, so I'm not sure you should be using the `env34` environment if you want do want to use Anaconda